# site not loading with the www. prefix ( PyroCMS)

Tags: cms

I am using PyroCMS 2.1 pro. With multi site manager.

I have a website that I have setup as somedomain.com.au.

It works fine, however when i type in the www. prefix the CMS tells me its not setup.

If I go into the CMS and change the domain to www.somedomain.com.au it works but then doesnt work if we ommit the www.

Should I be redirecting something or have I missed a setting in PyroCMS that I should have set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `.htaccess` to redirect one version (for example the not-www) to the other (the www). The following is an example to redirect the not-www version to the www version.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter which you choose, but you have to pick one and stick with it.

If you're looking to use the `www` prefix, see http://wwwizer.com for an easy way to automatically redirect the naked domain to the `www` subdomain. This can also be done with Apache rewrite rules, but since it sounds like you're on shared hosting, the other method sounds more reasonable.

If you want to REMOVE the `www` then you'll need to look both into the redirects, and any options your hosting provider offers you. I know for a fact that many web hosts let you redirect the `www` using their own tools.